# Create complete DEF file of MSVC library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw

I have the following problem. I want to use a library compiled with VC6 with mingw. There is the header file, the dll file and a lib file, so it should not be a problem (at least a thought). The problem is every tool I tried (dumpbin, pexports, reimp, gendef) does not create the '@n' after the function names which are needed.

Yes I could add this by hand, but there are not just a hand full of functions.

Maybe one of you have an idea.

Comment: Stop. The @n is not your only problem. Just adapt to and recompile with Mingw; is probably faster, but at least safer.

Comment: It is the problem. Without it I get complains about unresolved references. So I added @0 to a function without parameters and build a lib file with dlltool and it worked. But I cannot add it to every function by hand.

Comment: The @n decoration is only generated when you declare the calling convention of the exported function as `__stdcall`.  That matters a great deal to whatever code uses your DLL, it needs to know the calling convention as well.  The default is `__cdecl`.  Using these declarators in the .h file is never the wrong thing to do, it avoids nasty accidents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is one of the "drawbacks" of cross-compiler usage of shared libraries. The `@n` is part of a so called *name mangling*, where symbols are exported from the shared library in a special way so that they can be referenced to by the linker when building another project.

Problem is: Name mangling is not stream-lined, so every compiler does it's own mangling (Microsoft VC++ and GCC), they do it totally differently.

Name mangling encodes the signature of an exported function into the name of the symobl - that's where all these `@` and `?` signs come into place. When you create a .def file with e.g. dumpbin, which is a Microsoft tool, it will create symbols for the Microsoft mangling format. MinGW GCC uses mangling for GCC which looks symbols up differently when linking.

One of your options is, as you suggested, to manually correct these symbols in the created .def file, but this is very cumbersome and ineffective unless automated. Worse is, that the Microsoft name mangling is proprietary, and although some people have put high effort into analyzing the mangling scheme, it is very unlikely that there is a tool that converts Microsoft symbols to GCC compatible symbols (at least I am not aware of such tool).

Another approach would be, and this is very common in such scenarios, to export the symbols as `extern "C"`, you might have seen this before. It basically removes mangling and exports the symbols 'as is' with just the name of the function. But this requires that you have access to the sources of the MSVC6 library, which you, I assume, do not have.

If you really need to use this library, you could also write a wrapper yourself, by creating a MSVC library that imports the lib, provides a function for each of the symbols, and exports them as `export "C"` itself. But this can be very tricky when dealing with classes, so I wouldn't recommend it.

So you are given five options here:

1) If you have the sources, just recompile with MinGW. That's the best possible and clean approach.

2) Find a tool that converts MSVC symbol names to GCC names (I don't know if there even exists any).

3) Manually change the symbol names in the .def file to be conform to your GCC mangling. If all your functions just require the `@n` at the end, I would suggest writing a small program that does this automatically if none of the other options are good for you.

4) Re-compile the code to export symbols as `extern "C"`.

5) Write a library with MSVC that wraps all symbols and exports them as `extern "C"` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I managed to get a lib working with mingw.